# Node.js - SyntaxError: Unexpected token * when import express

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, rxjs, ts-node

**node:** v10.16.3
**npm:** 6.12.0

I got a error when I import express in node.
I'm using this code https://github.com/angular-university/rxjs-course, look at `server/server.ts`.

I run `server.ts` with

```
$ ts-node ./server/server.ts
```

The related code is:

```
import * as express from 'express';
```

The error is:

```
import * as express from 'express';
       ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token *
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:23)
    at Module.m._compile (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:493:23)
    at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .ts] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:496:12)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ts-node/src/bin.ts:158:12)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
```

I already tried to change the code with:

```
import express from 'express';
```

Comment: `const express = require('express')` should work

Comment: yes, but I should modify all the application, now I'm getting an error related to `import {Application} from "express";` and the same for other files importing express, I need to fix this importing way

Comment: I see, which node version are you using?

Comment: node: v10.16.3  
npm: 6.12.0

Comment: es6 imports are an experimental feature in node v10.x, cf. https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v10.x/api/esm.html

Comment: Ok, I just tried it out and it works if in tsconfig you modify module and target to this: `"module": "commonjs","target": "es2017",`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved using @ktad's suggestion:

I added `"target": "es2017",` in `server.tsconfig.json`.

Here my full **server.tsconfig.json**:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es2017",
    "lib": ["es2017"]
  }
}
```